# Controlls missing on Google Maps API3 in Phonegap iOS App

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, phonegap-build

I am working on an app that is built using jQuery mobile and Phonegap. It has been working fine for over a year. Then a month or two ago, the controls (specifically map type, zoom, and street view) went missing without the app being updated, and only on iOS.

I have tried running the app through the phone's browser and it works fine. It is only after it has been compiled by phonegap (build) that the issue exists. I've attempted to manually force the UI settings to true, but only the map type control comes up. I have also tried modifying CSS to give the controls a crazy high z-index, and that made no difference either.

I have not been able to find any relevant information online. How can I get the controls to show up again?

Comment: No idea why this is downvoted.  We have seen the exact same issue with our apps on iOS.  As noted here we can add the mapType control manually but the other ones will not come up.  Trying different Maps API versions did not help.

Comment: @RobBaily I don't know if you were able to resolve your issue, but I came up with a work around after working with Google, check my answer if you're still having trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been in contact with Google, and it turns out a bug was introduced in version 3.32 that's causing this. They're working on it as far as I know, but came up with a workaround in the meantime.

First, you need to specify version 3.31 in the `script` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE&v=3.31"></script>
```

And then when creating the `mapOptions`, manually set the controls you want to true. In my case:

```
var mapOptions = {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    zoomControl: true
};
```

Comment: thanks for the update.  We will try this today and let you know if this works for us.  I thought I tried this with some older version but I am not sure.

Comment: Yes this worked for us as well!  You don't happen to have any link to a bug tracker for them that would tell us when a release fixes it?

Comment: @RobBaily Unfortunately not. They said they submitted it internally. What the means for us, I don't know.

Comment: I just got the notice from Google that they will be switching to version 3.33 as on August 14th.  I don't think we have tried 3.33 or 3.34 yet.  Have you tried either of these?  We will be trying them soon to find out but if you already have done so that would be good to know.  We will post our results as well.

Comment: I can't recall if I did 3.33.

Comment: Just so you know in our testing 3.33 did not work but 3.34 did.  You will probably want to have your app use 3.34 by August 14th as I think at that time 3.31 is no longer available.

Comment: Unfortunately all versions prior to 3.32 have [been deleted](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#documentation-for-the-api-versions) by Google and bug still persists in latest v3.34

Comment: 3.31 is no longer available, so this workaround does not work anymore. The answer provided by @Nikita Krasnov solves the actual issue.

Answer (score 7):

In my case I had a missing street view icon. Google Maps iframe didn't trigger `onload` event because Cordova rejected empty url of iframe.

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'
```

I set `<allow-navigation href="*" />` in config.xml

Comment: Works like a charm! Even better is using <allow-navigation href="about:*" />. Using the full wildcard is a bit of a hazard...

Comment: It seems like this is more complete than what I had below.  Not sure when this changed but the mod listed here seems to do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for usefull hint. Im using native WKWebView and by default I disabled loading any scheme except for "file" so I had to enable also "about" in `func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ...) { ... }`. See my answer for details.

Comment: Had the same issue with ionic5 + Google Maps JS API using Cordova. This fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

For those who do not use Phonegap but native WKWebView and you by default disabled any scheme except "file"... you must also enable "about" scheme in webView() func in ViewController.swift

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    var url = navigationAction.request.url;
    let scheme = url!.scheme;

    // open local scheme in WebView
    if (scheme == "file") {
        decisionHandler(.allow);
    }

    // needed to show google maps icons for controls like zoomControl and streetViewControl
    else if (scheme == "about") {
        decisionHandler(.allow);
    }

    // other schemes like fb/http/https/mailto open in external application
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(url!);
        decisionHandler(.cancel);
    }
}
```