# Zoom Controls on iOS are no longer visible

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, google-maps-api-3

After the update of google map API to 3.34 or 3.33 or 3.32 on iOS, the zoom controls and street view controls are no longer visible. The controls although are displayed on android version but iOS we no longer see the buttons. 
Is this expected behavior with the new release or is there any change required to get the options on iOS. 
We have even tried setting the zoom control options and street view control options as part of map options but still no luck.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow, please be sure to read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify yours so others can help you.

Comment: Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50048091/controlls-missing-on-google-maps-api3-in-phonegap-ios-app) it seems that it's a bug introduced in v3.32. However access to older versions have unfortunately [been removed](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions#documentation-for-the-api-versions) by google and in 3.34 bug is not fixed.

Answer (score -2):

Ah to be at the mercy of google maps UI changes.

Implementing your own controls is pretty trivial, just style them the way you want and add event listeners (below).

It's much safer to implement your own UI elements (for zoom, switching map types, etc) than rely on google's default (which can be changed with little notice, as you now realize).

```
<div class="zoom-control">
  <button class="zoom-in">Zoom In</button>
  <button class="zoom-out">Zoom In</button>
</div>

//the variable "map" must be already defined and an instance of google.maps.Map
document.querySelector('.zoom-in').addEventListener('click',function() { map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1); });
document.querySelector('.zoom-out').addEventListener('click',function() { map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1); });
```